# Image data-src in twitter bootstrap 3 carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make carousel work. I have just copied and pasted the code from examples website along with css. Carousel is working fine but images are not showing up in the slider. I have tried both relative and absolute urls but nothing is working. No errors are seen in console.

I have created a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/3327/

Here is the code (cut down to save space)

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img data-src="https://imly.s3.amazonaws.com/bootstrap/img/car13.jpg" alt="First slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Example headline.</h1>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img data-src="https://imly.s3.amazonaws.com/bootstrap/img/car14.jpg" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Another example headline.</h1>


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img data-src="https://imly.s3.amazonaws.com/bootstrap/img/car15.jpg" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
</div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

Here is the css:

```
.carousel {
  height: 350px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top:10px;
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
  z-index: 10;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel .item {
  height: 350px;

}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's nothing in the documentation for this. The image should just be inside a normal `src=""` attribute.

Comment: the code has been taken from getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/ and also the alt of image is being displayed

Comment: The data-src attribute is being created from the [holder.js](http://imsky.github.io/holder/) script which bootstrap are using in their docs, located [here](http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/docs.min.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use normal `<img src=""/>` tag

use `<img src="https://imly.s3.amazonaws.com/bootstrap/img/car13.jpg" alt="First slide">`

instead of

`<img data-src="https://imly.s3.amazonaws.com/bootstrap/img/car13.jpg" alt="First slide">`

**[Updated FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yashhy/52VtD/3331/)**

Comment: I saw this question and I was wondering if there would be an easy way to do the same, but curved (like with a 3D look) with bootstrap. Would you know the answer?

Comment: *curved* i'm clueless of what your asking, please post a question so it will explain clearly what your asking.

Comment: My question was kind of "has bootsrap an easy way for doing things like [this](http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/carousel.html)?" but I explained myself badly, hope you understand better with this. I don't post this as a real question, because it isn't I just thought that I would include this in the original question and that's why I am asking this here, but there is no problem if I don't get any answer.

Comment: its implemented with normal `css` and `html` so you can include these code in your bootstrap and bootstrap doesn't provide any kind of plugin for this.

Comment: then i don't see bootstrap as cool as people says. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @VdeVatman *bootstrap* is mainly used for **Responsive Designs** and not for **3D** graphics.